# Customize android search widget for scoped search

Tags: android, android-layout, search

I want to implement search filter in my android application. I have gone through the examples on how to integrate search filter and able to understand how to integrate it in application. But my requirement is to provide scoped search based a filter while doing search. I have tried to search similar implementations but was not able to find any examples. Please check section **Scoped Search** in this [UI Pattern](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/10/ui-patterns-for-mobile-apps-search-sort-filter/) collection, especially Dropbox example for iphone.

As mentioned before I was unable to find similar example in android but by looking at Dictionary.com 's application (snapshot shown below) I came to know that its possible in android also (of course by adding some more efforts in case its not possible with Search Widget itself). Can any one please provide any directions how I can implement similar scoped search in my application ?

Thanks for spending time on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following:
first i create a searchType layout for the alertdialog with the choose: (images, video, etc..)
then i create the activity for the search and implement the widget(like on android guide).

in the activity create a variable:

```
private String searchType = "";
```

then

```
...
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.YOUR_MENU, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
          //HERE INSERT THE CODE ABOUT THE ALERT DIALOG FOR THE CHOOSE 
          //THEN INSERT THE aALERT DIALOG RESPONSE INTO THE searchType VARIABLE
        }
}
```

Comment: @Contrariello Thanks for the answer. But if we set the tabs on OnQueryTextListener it will be called whenever query text is modified right ? I was able to achieve it through different approach that I will edit it the question itself.

Comment: mmm, you're right... ok well you can set another menu item and on click event show the alert. but if you want the tabs you can set the variable above in the onTabSelected()

Answer (score 0):

I have created a custom search widget that does not make use of the built in search functionality. Its simple to implement and can provide information to the current activity.
It also uses an Autocomplete textview so you can use Autocomplete, you could alternatively just replace this with a normal EditText.

```
public class CustomViewSearch extends View {

private CustomAutoCompleteView searchEditText;
private boolean viewShown = false;
private ActionBar actionBar;
private InputMethodManager inputMethodManager;
private OnEditorActionSearchListener onEditorActionSearchListener;
private List<String> dataItems;
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

public interface OnEditorActionSearchListener {
    void onEditorActionSearch(String searchText);

    void onTextChangedListener(String text);

    List<String> getNewItemsForSuggestions(String text);
}

public void setOnEditorActionSearchListener(OnEditorActionSearchListener l) {
    onEditorActionSearchListener = l;
}

// IMPORTANT: Provide your activity as the context
public CustomViewSearch(final Context context, List<String> items) {
    super(context);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View searchView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view_search_widget, null);

    actionBar = ((ActionBarActivity) context).getSupportActionBar();
    inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setCustomView(searchView);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

    dataItems = items;
    searchEditText = (CustomAutoCompleteView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_search);

    searchEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                onEditorActionSearchListener.onEditorActionSearch(searchEditText.getText().toString());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    searchEditText.requestFocus();
    searchEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            onEditorActionSearchListener.onTextChangedListener(s.toString());
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            dataItems = onEditorActionSearchListener.getNewItemsForSuggestions(s.toString());

            // update the adapater
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dataItems);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            searchEditText.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    });
    ImageButton closeImageButton = (ImageButton) searchView.findViewById(R.id.image_button_search_close);
    closeImageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (searchEditText.getText().length() > 0) {
                searchEditText.setText("");
            } else {
                hideKeyboard();
                actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
                actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);
                viewShown = false;
            }
        }
    });
    viewShown = true;
    showKeyboard();
}

public String actionClick() {
    if (!viewShown) {
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        searchEditText.requestFocus();
        showKeyboard();
        viewShown = true;
        return null;
    } else {
        return getSearchText();
    }
}

public void showKeyboard() {
    inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(searchEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}

public void hideKeyboard() {
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(searchEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
}

public String getSearchText() {
    return searchEditText.getText().toString();
} }
```

The corresponding xml layout for the search :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<za.co.android.CustomAutoCompleteView android:id="@+id/edit_text_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/empty_layout"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:paddingRight="36dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:hint="@string/search"
    android:textColorHint="@color/palette_primary_light_grey"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/image_button_search_close"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/empty_layout"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</FrameLayout>
```

The custom autocomplete widget code:

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomAutoCompleteView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

// this is how to disable AutoCompleteTextView filter
@Override
protected void performFiltering(final CharSequence text, final int keyCode) {
    String filterText = "";
    super.performFiltering(filterText, keyCode);
}

/*
 * after a selection we have to capture the new value and append to the existing text
 */
@Override
protected void replaceText(final CharSequence text) {
    super.replaceText(text);
}}
```

Usage of the CustomViewSearch widget:

Add a search icon to the menu.xml for the Activity. Then in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method - when the menu item is clicked, call the below function:

```
public void triggerSearch() {
    if (customViewSearch == null) {
        customViewSearch = new CustomViewSearch(this, null);
        customViewSearch.setOnEditorActionSearchListener(new CustomViewSearch.OnEditorActionSearchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEditorActionSearch(String searchText) {
                // DO SOME STUFF
                ((AppItemListFragment_) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.appitem_list)).searchTriggered(searchText);
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChangedListener(String text) {
                ((AppItemListFragment_) getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.appitem_list)).searchTriggered(text);

            }

            @Override
            public List<String> getNewItemsForSuggestions(String text) {
                return getNewAutoCompleteStrings(text);
            }
        });

    } else {
        String searchText = customViewSearch.actionClick();
        if (searchText != null) {
            // DO SOME STUFF
            ((AppItemListFragment_) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.appitem_list)).searchTriggered(searchText);
        }
    }}
```

I hope this helps - for me it was much easier to implement a custom search than use the built in one and provides a scoped search for any screen you are on.